# How do I concat corresponding values of two Pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, concatenation

I have a PD DF with three columns: lon, lat, and count:

```
lon    lat   count
123    456   3
789    012   4
345    678   5
```

And I'd like to concat lon and lat to make a fourth column so that the df looks like:

```
lon    lat   count  text
123    456   3      '123, 456'
789    012   4      '789, 012'
345    678   5      '345, 678'
```

I tried:

```
grouped['text'] = pd.Series([str(grouped['lon'])]).str.cat([str(grouped['lat'])], sep=', ')
```

But it appears to return:

```
lon    lat   text
123    456   '123, 456', '345, 678', '789, 012'
789    012   
345    678
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df[['lon', 'lat']].astype(str).apply(lambda r: ', '.join(r), axis=1)
```

Turn your integers into strings so that you can use them in `join`, then apply the join function for each row (i.e. across each row cell thus `axis=1`)

Another way:

```
df.astype(str).lon+', '+df.astype(str).lat  # astype optional if df already as strings
```

Comment: Clarified the question to show why that solution won't work (there's a third column). Should've included it in the original phrasing to be more precise; my bad

Comment: Sélect the two columns you need

Comment: `grouped['lon', 'lat']` returns `KeyError: ('lon', 'lat')`

Comment: It needs to be double brackets `[['lon', 'lat']]`

Comment: my edit was rejected; would you mind editing your answer to specify double brackets `df[['lon', 'lat']]` so that if some future soul stumbles across this they don't run into the `KeyError` I ran into? Thanks!